# npx work only with create-react-app package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npx

according to React JS Official docs, I have removed the create-react-app package from my system and after I try to create a new react project with `npx create-react-app app-name` command but it did not work for me, After I installed again create-react-app package globally now npx command work perfectly now I'm confused why npx does not work without create-react-app?

Comment: Maybe it's a conflict between `npx create-react-app` and global `create-react-app`. Try to remove the global package and then use `npx`.

Comment: Dear I had removed create-react-app but after npx create-react-app given me an error

Comment: What error? Does npx working for you with other commands than create-react-app?

Comment: Yes npx work with other packages like nodemon etc, now I have installed create-react-app globally and npx works fine but I want to delete create-react-app because it's installing the old react version

Comment: If you delete create-react-app, npx create-react-app should work fine..

Comment: No, it did not work with that package I had checked